# Qt Designer for PyQt on OSX 10.6

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

I liked Qt Designer on Windows so much for making GUIs for Python applications (using PyQt4) that I went and tried to install it on my Mac (under OSX 10.6.6).

At this point, I have successfully installed SIP, Qt4, and PyQt4.

The PyQt binary installers (for Windows) include a version of Qt Designer that works with PyQt. On OSX, there is no binary installer, just source. So no Qt Designer.

The Qt website offers Qt Creator as a download, but as far as I can tell, it requires that you're writing code in C/C++.

Is there a way to make Qt Creator work with PyQt? Or is there another GUI designer for PyQt that works on a Mac?

Thanks!
-Wesley

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've installed Qt4, then you have Qt Designer.  If you used the installer from qt.nokia.com, it should be in /Developer/Applications/Qt.

Qt Designer itself works just fine with PyQt. Qt designer just spits out XML describing the UI structure.  If you were using standard Qt with C++, you would have to run the `uic` tool to generate C++ from the .ui files.  Likewise, with PyQt4, you must run `pyuic4` on the generated .ui file to create python source from it.

If you're looking for a full IDE solution that handles all of this with PyQt automatically, I'm unaware of the existence of one.  I just have a `build_helper.py` script that processes all of my .ui files and places them in the appropriate place in the python package I'm developing.  I run the build helper script before running the actual main program to ensure that the generated code is up to date.

All of my .ui files go into a subfolder `ui` in the project root.  The script then creates python source and places it into 'myapp/ui/generated'.

For example:

```
import os.path
from PyQt4 import uic

generated_ui_output = 'myapp/ui/generated'

def process_ui_files():
    ui_files = (glob.glob('ui/*.ui'),
                glob.glob('ui/Dialogs/*.ui'),
                glob.glob('ui/Widgets/*.ui')))
    for f in ui_files:
        out_filename = (
            os.path.join(
                generated_ui_output,
                os.path.splitext(
                    os.path.basename(f))[0].replace(' ', '')+'.py')
        )
        out_file = open(out_filename, 'w')
        uic.compileUi(f, out_file)
        out_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_ui_files()
```

I also have a few other functions in there for running `pyrcc4` for resource compilation and `pylupdate4` and `lrelease` to generate translations.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Grant. I've downloaded the Qt4 installer from the nokia site, and it does include Qt Constructor. But as far as I know, there's no version of Qt Constructor that works with PyQt, instead of C/C++. The Windows yQt installer includes a version of Qt Designer that works with PyQt, but for installing PyQt on the Mac, there is only source. And with this source, no Qt Designer for PyQt. -W

Comment: I am just about to ask the same question. I think I still ask about it, as the focus is rather different

Comment: This is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212528/how-to-configure-qt-designer-to-load-pyqt-widget-in-osx I ask how to configure brew Qt Designer to load any PyQt widgets

Answer (score 1):

looks like You are looking for this :
https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

sweet and simple: QT designer for mac lighter and simpler than original QT creator .... just for python