# How to configure Qt Designer to load PyQt widget in OSX?

Tags: macos, qt, plugins, pyqt, qt-designer

Previously I work using PyQt extensively in Windows: its shipped PyQt include PyQt Designer that'll load any PyQt Designer Plugin developed using Python. This allow me to easily drag and drop those PyQt widgets in PyQt Designer.

I haven't compile PyQt from source, but what I get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044353/qt-designer-for-pyqt-on-osx-10-6), it seems like the source still not including PyQt Designer. Currently, I am using Qt and PyQt installed using brew.

So, how do we configure Qt Designer (the C++ one) to allow it load any PyQt widgets?

Answer (score 2):

The [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044353/qt-designer-for-pyqt-on-osx-10-6) to explains it very well. There is no such thing as "PyQt Designer". There is only Qt Designer, which should be installed along with Qt itself.

PyQt provides a plugin that enables [custom widgets to be written in python](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins) for Qt Designer. This plugin is installed by default when PyQt is installed, unless it was explicitly configured not to by using the `--no-designer-plugin` option.

If you start Qt Designer and open Help -> About Plugins, you should see some kind of python or pyqt plugin listed there - on Mac OSX, I think the plugin should be installed in `/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/designer/`).